# bootstrap 3 -> 5 navbar collapsible

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I have this navbar behaviour in bootstrap 5? It uses bootstrap 3. What I want is the navbar to hide the buttons and put them in the collapsible menu when the screen width is too small.
Here there is where I found the original code: https://codepen.io/isaac_dev/pen/ygWQzQ

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">bootstrap bay</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b>  </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Admin</li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Admin1</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Admin2</a> </li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Portfolio</li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio1</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio2</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read their own documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/)

Adding a snippet, a modified example from their own page.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Themes
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```